# Teiid wildlfy - Table column encrypt/decrypt

Tags: odata, wildfly, teiid

I am using teiid-wildfly server odata4 services to perform CRUD operations.  I need to store some of the table fields in encrypted format.  Could be possible for configure teiid security functions(AES_ENCRYPT) in vbd.xml file to perform encryption operations for specific fields in the tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you can provide the key those functions can be used to encrypt and decrypt as needed.

Comment: Thanks Steven Hawkins. Below is my vdb.xml and odata4 rest call is inserted  password column value as plain text to employee table. I have keys for encrypt/decrypt. Please let me how to do the security functions configuration in vdb.xml to store the password in encrypted format.  I am using Teiid 15.0.1 
<model name="PgDB">
<property name="importer.tableTypes" value="TABLE"/> <source name="test" translator-name="translator-postgresql" connection-jndi-name="java:/postgres-ds"/>
</mode>
**Rest call**
http://localhost:8080/odata4/ws/PgDB/emp
{
"name": "test",
"password": "test@12"
}

Comment: The simplest approach would be to create a view (with a key for odata access) that adds the encrypted value as part of an insert trigger: create view emp_view (name string primary key, password string) as select name, password from emp; create trigger on emp_view instead of insert insert into emp (name, password) values (new.name, aes_encrypt(new.password, {key}); -- where you'll obtain the key through something like a system property or other externalizable method.

Comment: Thanks Steven Hawkins. I configured the key as a system property in standalone-teiid.xml file and call aes_encrypt method inside the trigger as per the above instructions
create trigger on emp_view instead of insert as for each row  begin atomic
**insert into emp (name, password) values (new.name,aes_encrypt(new.password, ${aes_key}));**
end; 
Getting the error about aes_key value is not defined by any relevant group 
TEIID31118 Element "B05E533204139D03F24794CB862D53AF916D653F7DEB788D" is not defined by any relevant group.

Comment: As a system property, you can use the SYS_PROP('key name') function to get the key value.