# Teiid-wildfly Odata4 Server side validation

Tags: wildfly, teiid, odata4j

Please let me know if we can configure server side validation logic in vdb.xml file to validate the user input before insert values into database using teiid wildfly odata4 service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform custom validation in a way that is exposed to odata, you can create a view that has an insert trigger.  See [Teiid wildlfy - Table column encrypt/decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873020/teiid-wildlfy-table-column-encrypt-decrypt) - where a trigger is used to encrypt a value before it enters the database.